# Creating a new qwidget on exception using a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, pyqt

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import threading
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('click', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.mythread)

    def mythread(self):
        self.t=threading.Thread(target=self.action)
        self.t.start()

    def action(self):
        try:
            raise FileExistsError

        except FileExistsError:
            self.errorwindow = QtGui.QWidget()
            self.errorwindow.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 100)
            self.errortext = QtGui.QLabel('error', self.errorwindow)
            self.errorwindow.show()
            print('1')

def main():
    program = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a=Window()
    a.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 100)
    a.show()
    sys.exit(program.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

As it can easily be seen here, I am trying to make an "oops! an error occured" kind of window that would be created on an exception by a thread. This is an example code showing how I'm trying to do it and when you run this, you'll see that a window shows for a brief moment and then disappears. With my actual program, it even causes crashes. That `print('1')` was to see if the interpreter even gets to that line, and yeah it does, it prints '1'. So it's not that it doesn't run the exception block at all, it does but it just won't create a qwidget. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never do GUI operations from any thread except the one that created
`QApplication`. Thus, your exception handler must be run in main thread and called via signal-slot mechanism:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    somethingIsWrong = pyqtSignal(Exception)

    def run(self):
        try:
            raise FileExistsError
        except FileExistsError as e:
            self.somethingIsWrong.emit(e)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('click', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.mythread)

    def mythread(self):
        self.t = MyThread()
        self.t.somethingIsWrong.connect(self.handleException)
        self.t.start()

    def handleException(self, exception):
        self.errorwindow = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.errorwindow.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 100)
        self.errortext = QtGui.QLabel('error', self.errorwindow)
        self.errorwindow.show()
        print(exception.__class__)
```

Comment: I'll need to study `pyqtSignal` and `QThread` before I can fully understand this solution. Nonetheless, I tested this and it works, thank you.